# How to calculate weighted permutation probabilities in python

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, computer-science, probability

I have a string of numbers 0-12 with weights associated with them. The weights array is as follows: `[150000, 150000, 50, 150000, 150000, 800, 130000, 130000, 25000, 100000, 100000, 100000]`.

I have simulated all combinations of numbers 0-12 in Python but I want to write some additional code to simulate the probabilities of picking a specific combination, without replacement. For example, the probability of choosing (1,2,5,3) should be `(150000/total weight)*(150000/total weight-150000)*(150000/total weight-150000-150000)*(50/total weight-150000-150000-150000-50)`

I have no idea how to code this because of the "without replacement" part, I'm thinking of using a for loop that looks at the specific number in the position in the permutation and determine the probability of picking that number at that position but am hoping there is a way to look each individual permutation.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you have a string of numbers, but here is a working example for a list of ints which makes more sense in my opinion:

```
import random

weights =  [150000, 150000, 50, 150000, 150000, 800, 130000, 130000, 25000, 100000, 100000, 100000, 10000]
total_weight = sum(weights)
l = list(range(13))

tmp_weight = 0
new_weight = 1
for i in range(5):
    number = random.choice(l)
    print(number)
    new_weight *= weights[number]/(total_weight-tmp_weight)
    tmp_weight += weights[number]
    l.remove(number)

print(new_weight)
```

I am not sure if the logic is as you want it because your example wasn't clear.

You could build tuples with (number, weight) aswell. But you have to clarify your question first.

Edit after comment:
For a specific order of numbers it should work like this

```
perm = [1,2,3,4]
weights =  [150000, 150000, 50, 150000, 150000, 800, 130000, 130000, 25000, 100000, 100000, 100000, 10000]
total_weight = sum(weights)

tmp_weight = 0
new_weight = 1
for number in perm:
    new_weight *= weights[number]/(total_weight-tmp_weight)
    tmp_weight += weights[number]

print(new_weight)
```

Comment: thank you so much for answering! so basically the numbers 0-12 represent a weight. that's why you don't use random because the numbers chosen aren't random. does that make sense? so if you have the permutation (1,2,3,4) the probabiltiies are (150000/total weight)*(150000/total weight-150000)*(150000/total weight-150000-150000)*(50/total weight-150000-150000-150000-50) of choosing that permutation and i want to write a code that looks at the specific permutation (which isn't random) and calculates the probability of getting it

Comment: @ca123 I edited my answer. Maybe thats suitable for your problem

Comment: And the list of weights and the example of probability calculation aren't consistend. You said the range of numbers is 0-12 and the list of weights has length of 12 which should be 13. Be careful while indexing so you dont use the wrong values.